# Calculate total scheduled against total actual in two separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two tables in my schema. The first contains a list of recurring appointments - `default_appointments`. The second table is `actual_appointments` - these can be generated from the defaults or individually created so not linked to any default entry.

Example:

**default_appointments**

| id | day_of_week | user_id | appointment_start_time | appointment_end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10:00:00 | 16:00:00 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 11:30:00 | 17:30:00 |
| 3 | 6 | 5 | 09:00:00 | 17:00:00 |

**actual_appointments**

| id | default_appointment_id | user_id | appointment_start | appointment_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-09-13 10:00:00 | 2021-09-13 16:00:00 |
| 2 | NULL | 1 | 2021-09-13 11:30:00 | 2021-09-13 13:30:00 |
| 3 | 6 | 5 | 2021-09-18 09:00:00 | 2021-09-18 17:00:00 |

I'm looking to calculate the total minutes that were scheduled in against the total that were actually created/generated. So ultimately I'd end up with a query result with this data:

| user_id | appointment_date | total_planned_minutes | total_actual_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-13 | 360 | 480 |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 | 360 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-09-18 | 480 | 480 |

What would be the best approach here? Hopefully the above makes sense.

**Edit**

OK so the `default_appointments` table contains all appointments that are "standard" and are automatically generated. These are what appointments "should" happen every week. So e.g. ID 1, this appointment should occur between 10am and 4pm every Monday. ID 2 should occur between 11:30am an 5:30pm every Thursday.

The `actual_appointments` table contains a list of all of the appointments which did actually occur. Basically what happens is a default_appointment will automatically generate itself an instance in the `actual_appointments` table when initially set up. The corresponding default_appointment_id indicates that it links to a default and has not been changed - therefore the times on both will remain the same. The user is free to change these appointments that have been generated by a default, resulting in setting the default_appointment_id to NULL * - or -* can add new appointments unrelated to a default.

So, if on a Monday (day_of_week = 1) I should normally have a default appointment at 10am - 4pm, the total minutes I should have planned based on the defaults are 360 minutes, regardless of what's in the actual_appointments table, I should be planned for those 360 minutes every Monday without fail. If in the system I say - well actually, I didn't have an appointment from 10am - 4pm and instead change it to 10am - 2pm, actual_appointments table will then contain the *actual* time for the day, and the actual minutes appointed would be 240 minutes.

What I need is to group each of these by the date and user to understand how much time the user had planned for appointments in the `default_appointments` table vs how much they actually appointed.

Comment: The concepts of `scheduled` and `created/generated` are not clear.  Which row represents a `scheduled` appointment and which row represents a `created/generated` appointment?  Is that all found in the one `actual_appointments` table based on `default_appointment_id` being `null` or not?

Comment: Apologies. Yes, the null value in `actual_appointments` denotes an appointment instance that has been manually created and therefore is not based on a default.

Comment: Well, that wasn't my question.  You have a concept of `scheduled`.  Which row represents a `scheduled` appointment?  Can you point out the rows in each table that correspond to the different sums you are trying to calculate?  Even a tiny test case with data could help, with the exact result you would expect, given that data.

Comment: So any appointment within the `actual_appointments` table that has a `default_appointment_id` associated with it has been generated in the background  - so essentially scheduled and created by a background job. Any other instance within the table which has a null value is one that has been manually created by a user. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: @DanielBarnes . . . It is not obvious to me how an actual appointment with a `NULL` id is being matched to a default.  Or how the data in the default appoints is being turned into a date.  Something isn't being explained.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies, i've updated my question. There's no guarantee that an actual appointment is related to a default. Defaults are generated but the user is free to change them, or freely add their own, so I need a comparison between what should have been the default for the week, and what actually was appointed for the week. If the default is changed, it no longer relates to a default and is a standalone instance.

Comment: @DanielBarnes Check the updated answer.  The result matches your expected result.  It also shows one way to generate those planned appointments over any range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted based on new detail in the question.
Note: I used day_of_week values compatible with default MySQL behavior, where Monday = 2.

The first CTE term (`args`) provides the search parameters, start date and number of days.  The second CTE term (`drange`) calculates the dates in the range to allow generation of the scheduled appointments within that range.

`allrows` combines the scheduled and actual appointments via `UNION` to prepare for aggregation.  There are other ways to set this up.

Finally, we aggregate the results per user_id and date.

The test case:

[Working Test Case (**Updated**)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fb6fe837292646f1691c4e9e699cc4d)

```
WITH RECURSIVE args (startdate, days) AS (
       SELECT DATE('2021-09-13'), 7
     )
   , drange (adate, days) AS (
       SELECT startdate, days-1 FROM args UNION ALL
       SELECT adate + INTERVAL '1' DAY, days-1 FROM drange WHERE days > 0
     )
   , allrows AS (
       SELECT da.user_id
            , dr.adate
            , ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(da.appointment_end_time, da.appointment_start_time))/60, 0) AS planned
            , 0 AS actual
         FROM drange AS dr
         JOIN default_appointments AS da
           ON da.day_of_week = dayofweek(adate)
        UNION
       SELECT user_id
            , DATE(appointment_start) AS xdate
            , 0 AS planned
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, appointment_start, appointment_end)
         FROM drange AS dr
         JOIN actual_appointments aa
           ON DATE(appointment_start) = dr.adate
     )
SELECT user_id, adate
     , SUM(planned) AS planned
     , SUM(actual)  AS actual
  FROM allrows
 GROUP BY adate, user_id
;

Result:

+---------+------------+---------+--------+
| user_id | adate      | planned | actual |
+---------+------------+---------+--------+
|       1 | 2021-09-13 |     360 |    480 |
|       1 | 2021-09-16 |     360 |      0 |
|       5 | 2021-09-18 |     480 |    480 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------+
```